# How to post Message in android facebook wall?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code to post on android facebookwall

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();


parameters.putString("message", string);
    try {
        mFacebook.request("me");
        mFacebook.request("feed", parameters, "POST");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Message posted to your facebook wall!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

but while posting I am getting this error.

```
    Key format expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was      
    returned.
    Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
   // class cast exceptions
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to byte[]
    at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1411)
    at com.facebook.android.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:63)
    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:182)
    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:208)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this parameters.putString("message", "write your Post to show on wall");

Comment: problem occur on this line "mFacebook.request("feed", parameters, "POST");"

Comment: try this mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST", new WallPostListener());